# htaccess alias use - load/get file from other directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

We would like to use the index of one directory to generate content in other (fake) directories. Searching here and everywhere for over a week didn't give any working results. 
The .htaccess Alias directive should do it, but we just can't seem to get it working. Here's the case:

This is the main dir and file where content loads from a database:

```
/news/index.php
```

These navigation links should load the index.php from /news, but with the cat ID's (this we have working):

```
/animal-news/cat=1
/car-news/cat=2
/music-news/cat=3
```

So these three dirs do exist (or rather not if possible), and the content is loaded from `/news/index.php`.

So far this is what we came up with (the url should be the same though: ie: /animal-news/cat=1/)

```
Alias /animal-news/cat=1/ /news/index.php?cat=1/
```

Anyhelp is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Post your existing .htaccess in your question.

Comment: I added a new line with the alias...

Comment: Alias isn't allowed in .htaccess, how is it working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alias isn't allowed in .htaccess, you will need to use mod_rewrite rules.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^=]+=[0-9]+)/?$ /news/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks so much...will try it soon and let you know!

Comment: Thanks anubhava! This worked perfectly - with some adjustments, but we did it thanks to you!

Comment: You're most welcome. Glad that it worked out for you.